# Why does powershell ignore the queryTimeout parameter for Invoke-DbaQuery and hang indefinitely?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, bamboo

I have a fairly straightforward Powershell script that is ran as part of a Bamboo deployment which includes a call to Invoke-DbaQuery to run sql scripts against a database.

After an incident with a bad script left our deployment hanging for hours, I am attempting to implement a timeout which I would expect to cause the Invoke-DbaQuery to fail, and thus the script to fail, and likewise the Bamboo deployment after a set amount of time.

However, Powershell seems to be ignoring the -queryTimeout parameter of Invoke-DbaQuery. Running the following commands calling an intentionally long running script and an arbitrarily short timeout, the query continues to execute hours after the timeout.

To eliminate variables I am testing this directly on Powershell on the server with the sql instance.

```
$path = "c:\somescript.sql"
$server = "localhost"
Invoke-DbaQuery -file $path -SqlInstance $server -Database MyDatabase -QueryTimeout 30
```

Comment: You should ask at the dbatools repo instead: https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/issues

Comment: Thanks. I have opened an issue over there now as well. Hoping perhaps someone here might have suggestions on a different or better way of handling this if the query timeout on invoke-dbaquery does not work

Comment: The obvious alternative is Invoke-SqlCmd https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually seeing similar behavior with Invoke-SqlCmd

Comment: Do you have a repro that shows this behavior with Invoke-SqlCmd?  Something simple like `invoke-sqlcmd "waitfor delay '00:01:00'" -QueryTimeout 30` works as expected.  And note that the timeout is per-query not per-script and only client network wait time counts against the timeout.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't finding that in the documentation. So to be clear, the QueryTimeout could not really be used to protect against something like a loop iterating over millions of records to perform a set of actions, since each action/query inside the loop would be processing in less than the timeout?

Comment: Technically the timeout is on each batch, not each query.  So a server-side loop would get timed out.